# How to set up the column names in the query which is generated by Breeze in case of expand?

Tags: javascript, entity-framework-6, breeze

I have the db structure and EF context below and I want to query the blog entries. In this case blog entry means the blog_entry (including id and title fields) and blog_body including body_with_markup and body_without_markup fields.

I have a query in Breeze like below and the result is that the **server gives back an 500 error because there is no 'BlogBody_Id' field**. I traced out the query generated by breeze-ef and the problem is that in the generated query 'BlogBody_Id' is used instead of 'Id'. I changed the column name in the query and the result was the desired result.

I can see two options in this case:

- I change the db column names accordingly (the db is small at the moment so It won't hurt me that much). Is there a guideline what to follow?
- there is a way to tell Breeze the column names can be used

My question is regarding to the second one. If it is possible how can I do it? I went through the documentation and I haven't found anything related to this issue.

```js
return EntityQuery.from('blogEntry')
                .select()
                .expand('blogBody')
                .using(newManager)
                .execute()
                .then(success)
                .catch(failed);

            function success(data) {
                console.log(data.results);
                return data.results;
            }

            function failed(msg) {
                console.log('error: ' + msg);
            }
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_ENTRY](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [IS_PUBLISHED] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [AUTHOR_ID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [CREATE_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CREATED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LAST_CHANGED_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [LAST_CHANGED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BLOG_ENTRY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_BODY](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BODY_WITH_MARKUP] [text] NOT NULL,
    [BODY_WITHOUT_MARKUP] [text] NULL,
    [BLOG_ENTRY_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATE_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CREATED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LAST_CHANGED_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [LAST_CHANGED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BLOG_BODY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_BODY]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Blog_Body__Blog_Entry_Id] FOREIGN KEY([BLOG_ENTRY_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BLOG_ENTRY] ([ID])
```

```c#
public class BlogEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int IsPublished { get; set; }

        public BlogBody BlogBody { get; set; }
    }

public class BlogBody
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BodyWithMarkup { get; set; }

        public string BodyWithoutMarkup { get; set; }

        public int BlogEntryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the issue is not at breeze side rather there is no foreign key annotation between the objects. I set up the relation between the objects and it is working fine now.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer (when SO allows) so that we know this is no longer an open issue. Glad Breeze is working for you :-)